# Why does keep from purrr return NULL within map?

Tags: r, purrr

I need to compare strings within nested `tibble`s. This is how my data looks:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata = data.frame(
  Months = c(1 ,1 ,1 , 2, 2, 2),
  Strings = rep(c('1', '2', '3', '1', '3', '4'))
)
```

I need to return that one string from the previous month that did not appear in the current month.

I use this code to do so.

```
output = mydata %>%
  nest(Nested = -Months) %>%
  arrange(Months) %>%
  mutate(Lost= map(Nested, lag(Nested), .f = function(.CurrentMonth, .PreviousMonth){
    length(keep(.PreviousMonth$Strings ,!.PreviousMonth$Strings %in% .CurrentMonth$Strings))
  }))
```

But `output$Lost` contains zeros even though the line

```
length(keep(output$Nested[[1]]$Strings, !output$Nested[[1]]$Strings %in% output$Nested[[2]]$Strings ))
```

works fine and returns 1.

Comment: Currently hard to reproduce. Please edit as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @NelsonGon , yes, sure. Thanks!

Comment: Where did `.CurrentMonth` and `.PreviousMonth` come from?

Comment: @ÉricoPatto , ```.CurrentMonth``` is ```Nested```, ```.PreviousMonth``` is ```lag(Nested)```. Since they came from the single variable, I used ```map```

Comment: Try this `mutate(Lost = map2(lag(Nested), Nested, setdiff))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `map` with `map2` within `mutate` results in the correct output.